# Summation simplification in the definition of composition of linear transformation

Tags: summation

I'm reading a definition of composition of linear transformation, and I don't understand the second line in it. And I think that the part I don't understand is not directly related to linear transformation but the simplification of summation mark.

Say $\textsf{T}:\textsf{V}\to\textsf{W}, \textsf{U}:\textsf{W}\to\textsf{Z},A=[\textsf{U}]_{\beta}^{\gamma},B=[\textsf{T}]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$, and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ each has a cardinality $n,m,p$ respectively, and they're ordered bases. The work I've done is:

$$\begin{align}{}
\large\sum_{k=1}^{m}{B_{kj}(\sum_{i=1}^{p}{A_{ik}z_i})}\\
\large=\sum_{k=1}^{m}{(\sum_{i=1}^{p}{B_{kj}A_{ik}z_i})}
\end{align}$$

But I don't know how the swap between the two summation marks work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&(A_{1,1},A_{1,2},...,A_{1,m})\\
&(A_{2,1},A_{2,2},...,A_{2,m})\\
&\vdots\\
&(A_{p,1},A_{p,2},\cdots,A_{p,m})
\end{align*}
if you want to add them all together, one starts to add row by row, or you can do it through column by column.

Comment: So you meant that my $B_{kj}A_{ik}z_i$ is kind of your $A_{p',m'}$?

Comment: If there are more than three summation marks, would it still be true to randomly swap any two? It's hard to imagine/draw it and think...

Comment: As long as the indices of summation are independent.

Comment: You cannot swipe $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}$ as $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{i}\sum_{i=1}^{n}$.

Comment: Cool! And this rule also works for multiple-independent $\prod$ right?